# Ant merge structure

Tags: ant

What does the `includes="**/*.js"/` mean in the below merge code form an Ant file.

```
<target name="merge grid">
    <echo>${grid.file}</echo>
    <concat destfile="${grid.file}" fixlastline="yes" append="no">
    <fileset dir="${js.src.dir}/dvr/components/grid/" includes="**/*.js"/>
    </concat>
</target>
```

Also what does this part mean :

```
<target name="merge" depends="merge grid, merge solids"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fileset

```
**/*.js
```

matches files in the filesystem.  The `**` part means 'in any directory' (under the directory mentioned in the `dir` attribute). The `*.js` matches any file ending in `.js`.  Overall, the fileset includes any `.js` file found in a sub-directory of `${js.src.dir}/dvr/components/grid/` recursively.  *See [Directory-based Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html).* (The trailing `/` is not part of the includes pattern, it is the closing part of the fileset element in the XML:

```
<fileset ... attributes ... />
```

The `merge grid` target, therefore will concatenate all `.js` files into a single destination file of name defined in the property `grid.file`.

The `target` is the opening of the definition of an Ant target, which is a sequence of Ant tasks that comprise a distinct step in the build.  The `depends` attribute lists other targets - in this case `merge grid` and `merge solids` - that must be executed (if needed) before the `merge` target itself.  *See [Targets](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html).*

Comment: **/*.js does this then mean its going to include all js files in the grid folder then all js files in the component folder, then all js files in the dvr folder. Or it just means all js files including any sub folders inside the grid folder but not any JS files outside the grid folder.

Comment: @Chapsterj - the `**` means that it is a recursive search and will include matching files in each child directory below the grid directory.  It _won't_ recurse back up the tree through the components and dvr dirs though.